# flutter Change Icon which shows while viewing Background running apps

Tags: flutter, launcher-icon

How to Change below Icon in flutter. it is happening in Nokia 8.1. 
App Icon in drawer is correct.

[image]

Below is my current res folder

[image]

Comment: if any answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending to have your application be multi-platform, then there is a [dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) you can use which takes care of generating launcher icons for both platforms.

You use it like so:

1. Add dependency to pubspec.yaml file

`flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4`

2. In your pubspec.yaml file include the following attributes (based on your desires)

   ```
   flutter_icons:
      android: "launcher_icon" 
      ios: true
      image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
   ```
3. Make sure to get packages (`flutter pub get`)

You can read more in the [documentation](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the android folder in the project outline. Go to New > Image Asset. (Try right clicking the android/app folder if you don't see Image Asset as an option.) Now you can select an image to create your launcher icon from.

[image]

This will replace the current launcher icons. You can find the generated icons in the mipmap folders:

[image]

Comment: the reason why this solves the problem, is that it also creates an adaptive icon